# Fluentmigrator in database schema

Tags: c#, .net-core, database-schema, fluent-migrator

I use Fluentmigrator in my Visual Studio project to version and migrate a single MS SQL Server database.

Within that db, there are multiple customer dedicated database schemas,
and wish to migrate them independently from each other,
hence each schema would have a dedicated **VersionInfo** table.

I see this might be possible with this, by overriding the meta data:
https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/version-table-metadata.html

The next step would be to execute sql scripts against the target schema using

```
Execute.EmbeddedScript("...")
```

statement in the migration class,
but I don't see the **InSchema** member method.

(Unfortunately I need to use embedded scripts, as I have complex temporal table structure setups.)

How could I run **Execute.EmbeddedScript** against different schemas?
The schema name is passed to my fluent migrator application via command line argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad its open source, found it in the code.
EmbeddedScript function has a 2nd optional parameter which is a dictionary, where you can list tokens to be replaced in your to be executed sql code.

This is where it got implemented, but since then it got improved
https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues/625
and now the token key has to be in $(mytokentoreplace) in the sql script,
and just "mytokentoreplace" in your c# dictionary which you pass to Embeddedscript to replace the tokens to whatever you want.

You can pass in your dictionary to your migration classes using dependency injection:
https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/obsolete/app-context.html

then just call
Execute.EmbeddedScript("mysqlscript.sql", service.Tokens);
to replace the tokens, which in my case is schema.